# Pygame doesn't draw rectangles on the screen after a specific threshold

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a visualisation for various sorting algorithms and I was playing around with **Pygame** to try and draw the rectangles that I need.

In the below code, the user is given multiples inputs: the **lowest value** of the list to be sorted, the **highest value**, and the **number of elements** the list is going to have. The elements are going to be **randomly** generated.

Then I'm getting the user's screen size so that I can have an appropriate window for the visualisation. Based on the visualisation window and the user's input, I'm setting up the **width** and **height** of the rectangles, so that each rectangle has the same width and that they are scaled based on the **highest value**.

Almost everything is nice and fine with this approach, but there's one thing that I can't figure out. It seems that setting the **number of elements** (***n***, in the code below) too high, the rectangles are not being drawn.

My asumption is that after a specific threshold, ***RECT_W***, which is the width of the rectangles, becomes to small for **Pygame** to draw it.

What options do I have to solve it, except of having the **number of elements** smaller than a specific value?

```
import random
import pygame
import color_constants as colors
import ctypes
import copy
from pygame.locals import *


# Read data based on user's input
def readData():
    listOfNumbers = []
    data = dict()

    print("Lowest Value: ")
    numLow = int(input())

    print("Highest Value: ")
    numHigh = int(input())

    print("Length of list: ")
    n = int(input())

    for i in range(0, n):
        listOfNumbers.append(random.randint(numLow, numHigh))

    origLst = copy.copy(listOfNumbers)
    data.update({'lst': origLst})
    data.update({'numLow': numLow})
    data.update({'numHigh': numHigh})
    data.update({'n': n})
    data.update({'sorted': listOfNumbers})

    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = readData()

    # Getting the user's screen size
    user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
    SCREENSIZE = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0)-100, user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)-100
    SCREEN_W = SCREENSIZE[0]
    SCREEN_H = SCREENSIZE[1]

    # Setting and scaling the size of rectangle based on the number of elements (n)
    # and the highest number (numHigh)
    RECT_W = SCREEN_W // data['n']
    RECT_H = SCREEN_H / (data['numHigh'])

    # Setting up the color literals
    RED = (255, 255, 255)
    GRAY = (0, 0, 0)

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREENSIZE)

    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                running = False
        screen.fill(GRAY)

        for i in range(data['n']):
            rect = Rect(i*RECT_W, 0, RECT_W, RECT_H * data['lst'][i])
            rect.bottom = SCREEN_H
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, rect)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: If `data['n']` is greater than `SCREEN_W`, `RECT_W` is 0

Comment: All right, that seems an easy fix by doing this `RECT_W = SCREEN_W / data['n']`, so that `RECT_W` it's a float. But I still get the same result

Comment: Of course a coordinate is truncated when drawing. You cannot draw a fraction of a pixel. The size of the rectangle can only be integral 0, 1, 2 ... You cannot draw a rectangle with a size < 1.

Comment: So the only option is to have the `number of elements` smaller than `SCREEN_W` ?

Comment: You can draw the rectangles on a large surface and scale down the surface. However, the rectangles get blurred. So, no. There is no good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `data['n']` is greater than `SCREEN_W`, `RECT_W` is 0. A coordinate is truncated when drawing. You cannot draw a fraction of a pixel. The size of the rectangle can only be integral (0, 1, 2 ...). Hence, you cannot draw a rectangle with a size less than 1.
You can draw the rectangles on a large surface and scale down the surface. However, the rectangles get blurred. So, this is no good option.